# crystal report summary calculation

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a listing of clients grouped by zip code.  i have only an interest in the total number of clients in each zip code grouping.  I am trying to limit my report to a certain number of groups determined by the user entering a percent as a parameter. For example this is the list of zip code information

```
zip code c   50 clients    50% of total clients
zip code d   25 clients    25% of total clients
zip code e   10 clients    10% of total clients
zip code a   10 clients    20% of total clients
zip code b    5 clients     5% of total clients
```

(They have been sorted in order descending order)

Print the report listing the top 80% of total clients.

I have tried using the percentofdistinctcount summary field but I can't get the program to add the values together to meet but not exceed the percentage given as the parameter, 80% in this case.  If I try to enter Sum(percentofdistinctcount(fieldname)) I get an error telling me the field can't be summarized. 
thanks

Comment: To be honest couldn't understand your requirement... you need clients less than 80% or more than 80% also why are doing sum of `%` and are you calculating percentage locally or you are getting from database?

Comment: My list has 40 zip codes,  most have very few clients so rather than print the entire list every time, I want the option to limit the list to x% of the total,  usually this would be the top 80% of clients but the user should have the option of changing the percentage.

Comment: I am calculating the percentages locally.

Comment: While waiting for a response i tried this-  it gets me close to the correct result but the percentage doesn't add up correctly:                                                   NumberVar x;
x:=x+ PercentOfDistinctCount ({EntClients.IDClient}, {EntClients.Zip});
x<={?<Percent>};

Answer (score 0):

To the extent you understand the problem use below solution.

You are using a parameter for the percentage and at the same time you are showing data with that input of the paramter.

In this case you need to calculate percentage for all `zipcodes` in the report and then `conditinally supress` as per the user input.

Example:

```
if percent value<80
then false
else true
```

After the supress apply your summation contion on the displayed results.

If this doesn't help you I apologize